# Using eccodes in a Google Cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pip, google-cloud-functions

I've written a Python program that uses Xarray and Cfgrib to open .grib2 files. Cfgrib has eccodes as a dependency. Eccodes can be installed using conda, but I can't use that method in a Google Cloud Function. The eccodes pip package contains only the bindings, the actual package has to be installed manually: https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/ECC/ecCodes+installation. I'm able to build and install eccodes locally (using conda and manual install+pip bindings), but I'm stuck trying to install eccodes in Google Cloud.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**Cloud Functions** doesn't support custom packages that can't be installed using `pip` or packaging with your code.

**Cloud Run** would be better suited to your requirements, as it allows for a Dockerfile where you could specify custom actions to install the ecCode dependencies. And the resulting services can have the same characteristics as a Cloud Function (scale-to-zero, http/pubSub/eventarc triggers, etc.)

**Example Dockerfile snippet**

```bash
ARG ECBUILD_VERSION=3.3.2
RUN set -eux \
    && mkdir -p /src/ \
    && cd /src \
    && git clone https://github.com/ecmwf/ecbuild.git \
    && cd ecbuild \
    && git checkout ${ECBUILD_VERSION} \
    && mkdir -p /build/ecbuild \
    && cd /build/ecbuild \
    && cmake /src/ecbuild -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    && make -j4 \
    && make install
```

Example project: https://github.com/DeutscherWetterdienst/python-eccodes/blob/master/Dockerfile

**Deploy Command**

```bash
gcloud run deploy SERVICE_NAME --source .
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous answer, here's a link to the list of [System Packages Included in Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/system-packages).

You may also try the experimental feature posted on [PyPI eccodes 1.6.1](https://pypi.org/project/eccodes/):

```
$ git clone https://github.com/ecmwf/eccodes-python
$ cd eccodes-python
$ pip install -e .
$ python builder.py
```

Please be advised that this is still an **experimental feature** and does not guarantee that this would work 100%.

You may also [file a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187195&template=1163154) so that it would be included in future updates of Cloud Functions. We don't have a specific ETA for this but you can keep track of its progress once the ticket has been created.